# Came vs Came up (to my mind)

Tags: verbs

I had an argument with a friend on which one to use:

> I was thinking about old days and memories of you **came/came up** to my mind

Answer (score 3):

Probably the most natural is: *...memories of you **came to mind**.*

Neither “up” nor “my” are needed.

I wouldn’t use *came up* with *my mind*. This would be fine, though:

> We were reminiscing about old days and a story about you ***came up***.

If I wanted to use “my mind”, I’d use *into*, not “to”:

> I was thinking about old days and memories of you came ***into*** my mind.